# Is there a general term formula for 3 queens problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms

The specific question description is: Put 3 queens on a chessboard of M columns and N rows, how to determine the number of ways that no two of them are in attacking positions?

Note that M is not equals to N, and M/N are larger than a `Integer` in C language so that there is no way to solve this question using classical computer algorithm like DFS/BFS(for time and memory complexity considerations).

I guess this problem can be calculated by the mathematical method of **permutations** or **combinatorics**, but I am not good at math, so, please help me.

Comment: If the problem involved Rooks, rather than Queens, the computation would be $\binom{M}{3} \times \binom{N}{3} \times 3!$, since you have to choose $3$ columns out of $M$, $3$ rows out of $N$, and then *marry* the $3$ columns with the $3$ rows,  However, since Queens are involved, you have to *somehow* deal with the consideration of *diagonals* (**and better you than me**).

Comment: Thank you first! Actually, I have contemplated this problem for days, and I even tried to got the number of Rooks game then subtracted the number of situations of diagonals from the Rooks number. But, it is too complicated for me to find out every diagonals situations.